# Produce single out file from multiple lists in python

Tags: python

How to write the text file (outfile.txt)from three lists (years,animals,and sales)?

```
years=['2009','2010']
animals=['horse','cat','dog','cow','pig']
sales=[[2,300,700,50,45],[4,9,55,69,88]]

with open ('outfile.txt','w' as outfile):
    outfile.write(???
```

The outfile.txt should look like:

```
animals years_2009 years_2010 
horse 2 4
cat 300 9
dog 700 55
cow 50 69
pig 45 88
```

Comment: @aIKid, he did include what he was trying (though it was obviously and incomplete solution to the problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This handles cases where there are a variable number of years.

Python 2.7:

```
import itertools
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write('animals ' + ' '.join('years_' + y for y in years) + '\n')
    for data in itertools.izip(years, animals, *sales):
        outfile.write(' '.join(data)+'\n)
```

Python 3.*:

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    print('animals', *('years_' + y for y in years), file=outfile)
    for data in zip(animals, *sales):
        print(*data, file=outfile)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would split up the list of sales figures, and then just zip over the values:

```
s = ['2009', '2010']
animals = ['horse', 'cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'pig']
sales = [[2, 300, 700, 50, 45], [4, 9, 55, 69, 88]]

sales_09, sales_10 = sales

with open("animals.txt", 'w') as w:

    w.write("{0:^10}{1:^10}{1:1^0}\n".format("Animal", s[0], s[1]))
    for animal, nine, ten in zip(animals, sales_09, sales_10):
        w.write("{0:^10}{1:^10}{2:^10}\n".format(animal, nine, ten))
```

Output file:

```
  Animal     2009   2010
  horse       2         4     
   cat       300        9     
   dog       700        55    
   cow        50        69    
   pig        45        88
```

Comment: @aIKid Like it? If there's anything I can do to improve, please say so.

Comment: I think not. The results are nicely formatted.

Answer (score 1):

```
years = ['2009', '2010']
animals = ['horse', 'cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'pig']
sales = [[2, 300, 700, 50, 45], [4, 9, 55, 69, 88]]

with open('out_file.txt', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write("""animals years_{0} years_{1}""".format(years[0], years[1]))
    for i, _ in enumerate(animals):
        fp.write(animals[i], sales[0][i], sales[1][i])
```

Output

```
animals years_2009 years_2010
horse 2 4
cat 300 9
dog 700 55
cow 50 69
pig 45 88
```

Comment: OP wants files _written_.

Comment: @Games Brainiac, check the update now